# How do I know who downvoted my posts?

Tags: support, voting

Is it possible to know who downvoted my posts? I tried to find a way and I searched on the site but I didn't find anything.
Is it possible?
Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, that is not possible. Not even ♦ moderators can see who (up or down)voted a post. This is [by design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/12984/295232). If you ever think you're [being targeted with multiple downvotes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126829/295232), the system, staff or moderators will likely reverse it (see the link for more details).

Answer (score 3):

No, it‘s not possible to find out who up- or downvoted a post.

See [Is there a way to see who voted on your posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12984/is-there-a-way-to-see-who-voted-on-your-posts) for a more detailed discussion of the topic.